# Регулярные выражения: не получается изменить жадность

Tags: php

```
"@/(.*?)2a@"
```

Вырывает всю строку в строке

```
/123/456/789/000.2а
```

Хотя нужно вырвать 000

Добавление модификатора U не помогает

```
"@/(.*?)2a@U"
```

Comment: Почему 000, а не 0?

Comment: цифры это условно, там буквы цифры

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Самый нежадный очевидно будет одним символом, а не тремя. Из каких соображений регулярка должна понять что нужно три символа?

Comment: И куда вы потеряли точку?

Comment: Регулярка должна вырывать все до первого /, а она вырывает до последнего /

Comment: А там слеш. Ну тогда вместо `.*` можно написать `[^/]+`

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$str = '/123/456/789/000.2а';
if (preg_match('/\/([0-9]+)\./', $str, $matches) !== 0) {
    # $matches[0] - все совпадение
    # $matches[1] - первое совпадение в ( )
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Модификатор U - включает Unicode! Не путай его с UTF-8!!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MFcmreAUhs